# How to get submenu dropdown with images in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a very beginner in wordpress.

1. I need to add submenus with images in wordpress. Let's assume Main menu has menu1, menu2, menu3, ...etc. and I need to add submenu1, submenu2, submenu3, ...etc under the menu2 as sub dropdown menus with featured images. Can anyone tell how to do that in wordpress?
2. Can I use two menu plugins simultaneously?

Comment: You shouldn't be asking people to do your work for you, you should be trying something first, and when you're having issues, to come and explain what's happening and what you're trying to do.

Comment: I got it. I was confused with plugins. and finally done. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should look for a mega-menu plugin or maybe use a custom theme that already includes one.

Answer (score 0):

this one is free and wellknown: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/megamenu/ (wellnown is important because of the docu and the community if you need help). This will be the easiest thing if you're new to wordpress.

**Correction after talkin to lee. He / she is right. The following part is the 'advanced" solution.**

I, after 10 years of WP development, would code my own function, hooking into the wordpress image uploader. Many scripts are allready included in wordpress / many functions are working out of the box. Image upload is one of those scripts / functions. 
So you can enqueue the script that wordpress delivers (see following link, 'Default Scripts Included and Registered by WordPress' > 'Media Upload'):
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

As a real example how to implement it, would be way too much in this answer, I am giving you this link: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-the-wordpress-media-uploader--cms-22011 (usually i wouldn't paste a link as a answer, but as this is a side-answer / tip i guess it's okay).

All the best

Comment: What relevance does your link to `wp_enqueue_script` have to do with creating your own function an dusing the Wordpress Media Uploader?

Comment: sorry that was maybe too short, as I wrote I would code my own function. Therefore you need to enqueue scripts. So it would be smart to jump to 'Default Scripts Included and Registered by WordPress' and just read what is allready in the package (as oshadhi said she's new to WP this a the place to start for her if she wants to write her own function). I am reffering to "Media Upload" - as it is possible out of the box

Comment: No, I know that, what was I getting at is that I don't think you should include that link, as it doesn't directly relate to what you've said.

Comment: Thank you @Lee I've added a comment about it to make it more clear but also give a hint to other users if they are looking for a similiar solution.